# How to combine STM32 HAL library with CMake, as it need file from project it linked to

Tags: cmake, stm32

For ones who dont know STM32 library structure.
The library is not projected to cmake use (or any another build system as i think).

It have a bunch of source\headers files

```
  stm32_hal.c
  stm32_hal.h
```

They are provided with git repository, as example https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4
This files is depended by user provided `stm32_hal_conf.h`

The structure of project is looked like.

```
\ Repository
\--- HAL submodule library 
\------ stm32_hal.c
\------ stm32_hal.h
\--- User library 
\------ lib.c
\------ lib.h
\--- Project sources (depended from HAL)
\------ main.c
\------ main.h
\------ stm32_hal_conf.h (file, HAL library depended by)
```

The main question - HOW?
Obiviusly compilation HAL as generic `add_library()` would fail, as HAL library doesnt have access and even dont know about stm32_hal_conf.h

There is a repository, where this problem seems solved, but there is too much high level CMake code-mess, i cant even make it works.
https://github.com/ahessling/STM32F4Template

I dont want to hard copy HAL to project and dont want to include files as lists.

The code samples:

HAL FindPackage()

```
function(FindCmsisSTM32F4)
    set(CMSIS_LIBRARY_NAME "LIB_CMSIS")
    set(CMSIS_PATH ./submodules/stm32cubef4/Drivers/CMSIS)
    list(APPEND CMSIS_INCLUDE
        ${CMSIS_PATH}/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include
        ${CMSIS_PATH}/Core/Include)
    set(CMSIS_STM32_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMSIS_PATH}/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/include)
    add_library(${CMSIS_LIBRARY_NAME} INTERFACE)
    target_include_directories(${CMSIS_LIBRARY_NAME} INTERFACE ${CMSIS_INCLUDE})

endfunction(FindCmsisSTM32F4)

FindCmsisSTM32F4()
set(LIB_CMSIS "LIB_CMSIS")
```

Project CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(STM32F4_CMSIS)

# Add sources to elf file
add_executable(${elf_file} ${sources})

# Link Generic stm32 libraries to project
target_include_directories(${elf_file} PUBLIC ./src) # hal_conf.h inclusion
target_link_libraries(${elf_file} PRIVATE ${LIB_HAL})
```

Comment: @Armandas, it solve some problems, after research im answer more constructive.

Comment: Good to hear. Please give the answer an up vote!